# "Memory and the Computational Brain" by Gallistel & King

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience

I am looking for opinions on this book particularly whether it is a suitable intro to the field of cognitive neuroscience. What I would not like is a book that is really a collage of introductory articles that bear little relation to one another. Several of the introductory books on Amazon are that way. That is no way to learn a subject, imo (but I digress).

Gallistel and King begin with Shannon's information theory, but do not imo go very far into the physiology of neurons nor do they discuss how the codes derived from brain activity are connected to human or animal behavior. What I am looking for is more comprehensive and thus a longer book. Is there such an introductory book?

Comment: To clarify, I am looking for an intro to cog. neuroscience that begins with information theory, continues on with the physiology of neurons, and ends with discussion of human or animal behavior. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in information theory and neuronal physiology, you shouldn't be looking for an intro to cognitive neuroscience, but rather cellular neuroscience.  Most applications of information theory in modern neuroscience are related to neural coding.  The classic (and recently updated) text is Kandel's "Principles of Neural Science".  Byrne and Roberts' "From Molecules to Networks" has a more quantitative approach, but is not as comprehensive.